# Using ORCID to obtain bibliographic data for coauthor network analysis

Tags: bibliometrics, databases, network-analysis

I'm trying to use ORCID to generate a full list of publications for a set of approximately 500 individuals, along with whatever associated metadata is available in that database. I'm trying to use ORCID because of difficulties with entity resolution when using other databases (some individuals are referred to with multiple different names, and some individuals share the same name).
I currently have a list of the faculty, along with their ORCID numbers.
I'm hoping to put together a csv or xls spreadsheet, with records/works as rows, and the associated metadata for each work. The most important metadata are the author names (ideally separated or easily separated into different cells), the journal names, and publication dates. The broader aim is to put together a network map of these researchers for further analysis.

Browsing the ORCID website however, there doesn't seem to be a way to aggregate information from multiple authors. Even on a single author's webpage, the only export feature seems to be a basic html-format list of works, and definitely does not list co-authors. Looking through the API documentation does not seem to provide a solution either. Even if I were to manually access each DOI and look at which authors are listed, the names of coauthors in each publisher are not really standardized, and do not seem to be matched to their ORCID profile, so I'd face the same entity resolution problem. Also it's a massive undertaking with possibly several tens of thousands of publications.

Hoping someone can give advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot directly obtain co-author data via ORCID's API alone.

But there is a workaround. You can make use of other Persistent Identifiers (PIDs) that you read out of ORCID's data (keyword "*linked open data*"). That is, using ORCID, you can first fetch the DOIs of an author's publications, and then, in a second step, use [CrossRef's API](https://github.com/CrossRef/rest-api-doc) (as in `https://api.crossref.org/works/{doi}`, [here is an example](https://api.crossref.org/works/10.1371/journal.pone.0158765)) to save the names and ORCIDs of the co-authors of their publications.